# how can I achieve something like this with flutter sliver app bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

I want to achieve the design provided below.

The design is scrollable with a tab bar. The scroll functionality has been achieved but the card between tab bar and sliver app bar is something I could not achieve.

The code I have tried

```dart
CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_sharp)),
            actions: [
              Container(
                height: 46,
                width: 46,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(width: .5, color: Colors.white),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.share_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 46,
                width: 46,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(width: .5, color: Colors.white),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              )
            ],
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .35,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text('Good food'),
                  RatingBar.builder(
                    unratedColor: Colors.black,
                    initialRating: 5,
                    ignoreGestures: true,
                    itemSize: 18,
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    allowHalfRating: true,
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                    itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
                      Icons.star,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    onRatingUpdate: (_) {},
                  )
                ],
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              background: Image(
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/food.jpg',
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 5,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/book1.png')),
              ),
            )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image: I want to achieve this design]

Comment: Does your white card contain tappable event.

Comment: The one containing image?